# ggplot can find lng and lat in dataset but leaflet cannot, "Need '+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84' "

Tags: r, ggplot2, leaflet, shapefile

I have a dataset form the public repo https://github.com/highsource/verbundkarte

Reading the dataset with st_read and plotting it with ggplot yields a beautiful map with correct lng and lat data.

```
df <- st_read("~/Verkehrsverbunde.shp")

map <- ggplot(df) + geom_sf(aes(fill=SHORTNAME))
```

I therefore assume, that the lng/lat values are included in the variable df$geometry. However, if I use leaflet, no matter what I try I end up with an error. For instance

```
df%>% leaflet() %>%
  addProviderTiles("CartoDB") %>%
  addPolygons(label = htmlEscape(verbunddaten$SHORTNAME)) %>%
  setView(lng = 10.3, lat = 51.9, zoom = 5.1)
```

ends up with

```
Warning messages:
1: sf layer is not long-lat data 
2: sf layer has inconsistent datum (+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=9 +k=1 +x_0=3500000 +y_0=0 +datum=potsdam +units=m +no_defs ).
Need '+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84'
```

I found [this](https://github.com/r-spatial/mapview/issues/72) beautiful conversation of which I understood basically nothing. Reading the data with readOGR as suggested [here](http://zevross.com/blog/2015/10/14/manipulating-and-mapping-us-census-data-in-r-using-the-acs-tigris-and-leaflet-packages-3/#convert-the-data.frame-back-to-a-spatialpolygonsdataframe) doesn't solve my problem.

How do I force leaflet to assume the same longlat and EPSG as ggplot?

Comment: I can't find the shape file (Verkehrsverbunde.shp) on the github you linked

Answer (score 0):

The data in your `Verkehrsverbunde.shp` shapefile is in a custom [traverse mercator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transverse_Mercator_projection) projection, where coordinates are expressed in meters. By contrast, r-leaflet expects data to be expressed in degrees of latitude-longitude, which would look like an [equirectangular projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equirectangular_projection) if/when plotted.

I'll guess that, contrary to your belief, `ggplot` is not using latitude and longitude in degrees, but rather *northing* and *easting* values in meters. The representation of the data might look similar for small areas.

In GIS terms, your data is using the [EPSG:31467](https://epsg.io/31467) CRS (Coordinate Reference System), as can be inferred by `proj=tmerc` and `datum=postdam`; r-leaflet expects data in the [EPSG:4326](https://epsg.io/4326) CRS.

The approach here would be to reproject your data, so that coordinates are in latitude-longitude as expected. There are plenty of ways to do this; running `ogr2ogr -t_srs epsg:4326 Verkehrsverbunde-latlng.shp Verkehrsverbunde-latlng.shp` on a command line, [using R](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/307432/sptransform-error-unable-to-find-inherited-method-for-function-sptransform), or [using QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/43848/how-to-re-project-shapefiles), amongst other methods.